# ORA-00905: missing keyword while Using [CASE]) Clause in WHERE condition in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm trying to run the two sets of queries on the same dataset with Both  ([AND/OR] and [CASE]) approaches, where one [AND/OR] is working and the other [CASE] is not working and getting "**ORA-00905: missing keyword**"

Condition is: For Columns [C1, C2, C3, and C4] any one column will contain a value remaining, and all will be null.

#### With AND/OR clause (Working...)

```
SELECT tbl1.R1, tbl1.R2
    FROM (select 'ABC' as A1, 
                 '1234' as R1, 
                 '11223344' as R2, 
                 '' as C1,
                 '1' as C2,
                 '' as C3,
                 '' as C4
         from dual) tbl1
    WHERE
        'ABC' = tbl1.A1 AND (tbl1.C1 IS NOT NULL AND ('1234' = tbl1.R1 AND '11223344' = tbl1.R2)) OR
        'ABC' = tbl1.A1 AND (tbl1.C2 IS NOT NULL AND ('1234' = tbl1.R1 AND '11223344' = tbl1.R2)) OR
        'ABC' = tbl1.A1 AND (tbl1.C3 IS NOT NULL AND ('1234' = tbl1.R1 AND '11223344' = tbl1.R2)) OR
        'ABC' = tbl1.A1 AND (tbl1.C4 IS NOT NULL AND ('1234' = tbl1.R1 AND '11223344' = tbl1.R2));
```

What's wrong? I'm doing this SQL queries:

#### With CASE Clause (Error)

```
SELECT tbl1.R1, tbl1.R2
    FROM (select 'ABC' as A1, 
                 '1234' as R1, 
                 '11223344' as R2, 
                 '' as C1,
                 '1' as C2,
                 '' as C3,
                 '' as C4
         from dual) tbl1
    WHERE
        'ABC' = tbl1.A1 
         AND CASE WHEN tbl1.C1 IS NOT NULL
                    THEN '1234' = tbl1.R1 AND '11223344' = tbl1.R2
                  WHEN tbl1.C2 IS NOT NULL
                    THEN '1234' = tbl1.R1 AND '11223344' = tbl1.R2
                  WHEN tbl1.C3 IS NOT NULL
                    THEN '1234' = tbl1.R1 AND '11223344' = tbl1.R2
                  WHEN tbl1.C4 IS NOT NULL
                    THEN '1234' = tbl1.R1 AND '11223344' = tbl1.R2  
                  ELSE NULL            
             END;
```

Why Error:

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Expected output:

```
R1      R2
1234    11223344
```

Comment: case is an `expression` (not a clause)

Comment: Also, you are attempting to return "sql logic" via that `case expression` as if it is some sort of dynamic sql. A `case expression` should evaluate to a single **value** per row (i.e. they **cannot** return a piece of sql logic such as `'1234' = tbl1.R1 AND '11223344' = tbl1.R2`)

Comment: @Paul Maxwell: Rajesh's `CASE` expression is completely valid in standard SQL resulting in a boolean value. The problem here is that Oracle SQL does not support the boolean data type. It has been requested for ages that they introduce the boolean data type, but I guess they shy away from all the work that this would involve. (They always argued that we can use CHAR(1) with Y/N or NUMBER(1) WITH 1/0, but the same argument would apply to dates and numbers as well, because you could represent them with strings, too. Quite obviously this was just an excuse not to have to tackle this.)

Comment: Thanks, @PaulMaxwell for making me understand.

Answer (score 4):

`'1234' = tmptbl.B AND '11223344' = tmptbl.C` is a boolean expression. That means you want the result of the `CASE` expression to be a boolean. Oracle SQL doesn't support a boolean data type, though, so the expression is invalid.

As a `WHERE` clause already is a boolean expression, you don't need `CASE` expressions there, anyway. Just use `AND`, `OR`, and the appropriate parentheses.

You probably want something along the lines of

```
WHERE tmptbl.A = 'CM'
AND (tmptbl.C IS NULL OR (tmptbl.B = 1234 AND tmptbl.C = 11223344))
```

Comment: Thanks! @Thorsten Kettner I'm able to do with AND/OR but was expecting with CASE.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that you should continue to use the boolean logic of and/or with parentheses for your where clause. However, to demonstrate how that case expression could be modified to work please consider this:

```
SELECT tbl1.R1, tbl1.R2
FROM (select 'ABC' as A1, 
             '1234' as R1, 
             '11223344' as R2, 
             '' as C1,
             '1' as C2,
             '' as C3,
             '' as C4
     from dual) tbl1
WHERE
     tbl1.A1 = 'ABC'
     AND CASE WHEN tbl1.C1 IS NOT NULL
                and '1234' = tbl1.R1 AND '11223344' = tbl1.R2 then 1
              WHEN tbl1.C2 IS NOT NULL
                and '1234' = tbl1.R1 AND '11223344' = tbl1.R2 then 1
              WHEN tbl1.C3 IS NOT NULL
                and '1234' = tbl1.R1 AND '11223344' = tbl1.R2 then 1
              WHEN tbl1.C4 IS NOT NULL
                and '1234' = tbl1.R1 AND '11223344' = tbl1.R2 then 1
              else 0
         END = 1
```

Here the case expression is returning a value (which is what they are expected to do).

Comment: Nice to see it's working. Will it make any impact on performance or both will be the same?

Comment: Almost impossible to predict impact on performance, you could study execution plans perhaps to learn if there is any discernible difference. Performance in affected by many things such as data volumes, indices, fresh statistics etc etc. Personally I avoid using case expressions in the where clause, far easier to stick with `and/or` plus `parenthesis`  when needed